# How to assign graph label for graph in pytorch geometric?

Tags: python, pytorch

**Question:** How can we assign a graph-level label to a graph made in PyTorch geometric?

**Example**: Let us say we create an undirected graph in PyTorch geometric and now we want to label that graph according to its class (can use a numerical value). How could we now assign a class label for the whole graph, such that it can be used for graph classification tasks? Furthermore, how could we collect a bunch of graphs with labels to form our dataset?

**Code**: (to be run in Google Colab)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

import torch
from torch.nn import Linear
import torch.nn.functional as F
torch.__version__

# install pytorch geometric
!pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cpu.html

from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import to_networkx, from_networkx

# Make the networkx graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add some cars 
G.add_nodes_from([
      ('Ford', {'y': 0, 'Name': 'Ford'}),
      ('Lexus', {'y': 1, 'Name': 'Lexus'}),
      ('Peugot', {'y': 2, 'Name': 'Peugot'}),
      ('Mitsubushi', {'y': 3, 'Name': 'Mitsubishi'}),
      ('Mazda', {'y': 4, 'Name': 'Mazda'}),
])

# Relabel the nodes
remapping = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(G.nodes(data = True))}

G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, remapping, copy=True)

# Add some edges --> A = [(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)] as the adjacency matrix
G.add_edges_from([
                  (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4),
                  (1, 2), (1, 3),
                  (2, 1), (2, 4), 
                  (3, 0), (3, 1),
                  (4, 0), (4, 2)
])

# Convert the graph into PyTorch geometric
pyg_graph = from_networkx(G)
```

Now how could we give this graph a label = 0 (for class e.g. cars)? Then if we did that for lots of graphs, how could we bunch them together to form a dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `pyg_graph` object has type `torch_geometric.data.Data`.
Inspecting the [source code of `Data` class](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/data/data.html#Data), you can see that it defines the dunder methods `__setattr__` and `__setitem__`.

Thanks to `__setattr__`, you can assign the label with the line

```py
pyg_graph.label = 0
```

or you can instead use `__setitem__` doing

```py
pyg_graph["label"] = 0
```

The two notations perform the same action internally, so they can be used interchangeably.

To create a batch of graphs and labels, you can simply do

```py
batch = torch_geometric.data.Batch.from_data_list([pyg_graph, pyg_graph])
>>> batch.label
tensor([0, 0])
```

and PyG takes care of the batching of all attributes automatically.